# Java API accessed from Angular/Node

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, node.js, rest

I found a project online (Jboss Teiid) that seems to only have a JDBC/Java API for connecting and managing the tool.  I want to build a web-app (preferably in Angular) to manage Teiid, but I'm honestly not sure the best way.  Would it be best to create a REST API to interact with Teiid since it only has a Java API?  The JDBC driver is good for querying data, but the JAVA API is the only way to administer the tool and perform admin functions which i need.

Is there a better way?  if there was a javascript client this would be easy, i'm just not sure the best route to connect my javascript web-app to this java tool.

Any thoughts/guidance greatly appreciated!

Thanks

API docs: http://docs.jboss.org/teiid/8.11.0.Final/apidocs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with a JBoss stack, then might as well use their tooling. [JBoss Forge](http://forge.jboss.org/) can scaffold both a JAX-RS REST service and your Angular front-end at the same time.